# ASP.NET Login using Vb.net and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, vb.net, servercontrols

Currently, I only know VB.NET; though, I'm studying ASP.NET, HTML, CSS and JQuery...
My first few objectives are for my webform is:

- User inputs `Username` and `Password`
- User clicks on Login `Button`
- If `Username` and `Password` is in Database then
- Hide `Username`, `Password` `Label` and `Textbox` (`LoginContainer`) and show some content
- Else `LabelError.Visible = true` "Username / Password mismatches!"

So I've got the login thing working, but I have no idea on how will I be able to hide the elements and controls of my login form properly without ruining the styles I made in the CSS such as background-image. Is it possible to code in the vb code-behind and use some jQuery?

I tried adding

```
<div id="LoginContainer" runat="server">
```

and doing the
`LoginContainer.Visible=false`
But its destroying my design.

---

### Page Code-Behind

```
'Page_Load
If Not IsPostBack Then
        LblError.Visible = False
        Contents.Visible = False
        Login_Container.Visible = True
End If

'Button1_Click
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        Session("ID") = dt.Rows(0).Item("Stud_ID").ToString
        Session("usertype") = dt.Rows(0).Item("usertype").ToString

        Contents.Visible = True
        Login_Container.Visible = False
Else
        LblError.Visible = True
End If
```

### Page Markup

```
<div id = "Login_Container" runat="server">
<tr>
<td id = "LblError" runat="server"> Username / Password Mismatch. </td>
</tr>
</div>

<div id = "Contents" runat="server">
<p> Wrote or put something awesome right here</p>
<p> Also on this part</p>
<p> And this part too.</p>
</div>
```

My `Login_Container` and `Contents` `div` tags have `background-image` declarations associated via **CSS**.

My problem is when I set the `visible` property of my controls to **false** in the code-behind, the `background-image` styles are also **not visible**.

Comment: the common login logic is that 'if logged-in successfully" then redirect to a new (protected) page, nobody using "hide" and "show" content in same login page. But anyway what do you mean by "its destroying my design"?

Comment: I have inserted a background image in the element in my stylesheet.css.

When I try to add the runat="server" and code it in the Page_Load to Visible = true

The background image is not showing.

Comment: I edit your requestion.. did some reformatting and rephrasing.. but I did not remove this sentiment, 'I have no idea on how I will hide the elements and controls of my login form'.. which seems like it should be removed, or rephrased.. you are doing it, which is indicated in your problem statement.

Comment: did you mean, 'properly' hide it.. (in accordance to your issue with the design aspect)..

Comment: Yeah sorry for the wrong grammar. And yes properly hide it since when I'm hiding the element or control, it removes the background-image I've inserted in the CSS Stylesheet. How will I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @NewBeeProgrammer, did you review my answer? did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the built-in ASP.NET login controls for security.

Here is a video describing the features you can use:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/login-controls

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't have time to address this earlier, I was running off to work.  The answer is actually quite simple; Though, it depends largely on project constraints.

wrap your `runat=server` controls in `div` tags, and apply your style declarations to them.

```
<div id="ContentWrapper">
    <div id="Contents" runat="server">
        <p> Wrote or put something awesome right here</p>
        <p> Also on this part</p>
        <p> And this part too.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
div#ContentWrapper {
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:0;
    background-image: url('<uri>');
    background-position: 100% auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
  }
```

---

### **or**,

you can turn the `p` tag markup into [HtmlControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well, by adding the `runat=server' attribute.

```
<div id="Contents" runat="server">
<p runat="server"> Wrote or put something awesome right here</p>
<p runat="server"> Also on this part</p>
<p runat="server"> And this part too.</p>
</div>
```

, then set all of the `Visible` Properties of the HtmlControls (aka the paragraph tags) within `Content` to `false`.

```
'Optionally: add a private function that takes a ByRef parameter
Private Sub DisableControl(ByRef ctrl as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl) 'I'm specifying fully qualified namespace to class for reference purposes..
    ctrl.Visible = false
End Sub


'Replace: `Contents.Visible = True` Line in Button1_Click
For Each ctrl As HtmlControl In Contents.Controls.OfType(of HtmlControl)
    DisableControl(ctrl)
Next
```